# Full Example XHTML document showing how to define additional attributes

Tags: xhtml, attributes, dtd

I am trying to extend an xhtml  document to allow extra attributes.

In the w3.org it gives an example like so:

```
<!ATTLIST a
  myattr   CDATA        #IMPLIED
>
```

See: 6.1. Defining additional attributes - 
http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/xhtml-modularization-19990406/developing.html#s_dev_attrs

However i am not sure where to put that statement.

I have tried adding it like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
    <!ATTLIST a
      myattr   CDATA        #IMPLIED
>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

But when I pick up the doc using DOM that extra DTD statement is ignored.

I have also tried:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [ 

    <!ATTLIST a
      myattr   CDATA        #IMPLIED
>
]>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
```

But that really caused DOM to throw a wobbly.

So I'd appreciate it if someone could show me a sample xhtml document that has an additional attribute defined.  (i.e minimal full doc that could validate)

As you might have guessed....xhtml is not my strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is correct, apart from the missing `</html>` end-tag. With that added it parses OK for me. What exactly “throws a wobbly”?

The `ATTLIST` declaration must indeed go in the DTD, the internal subset of which is within square brackets inside the `DOCTYPE` declaration.

(What are you hoping to achieve with this? Browsers don't care, even if they are running in native `application/xhtml+xml` mode. In normal `text/html` tag soup mode the DTD internal subset will just confuse them.)

Comment: I am using xhtml to store some content in the back-end. CMS-like. So, some resources might simply be defined by a meta tag <meta name="pageId" content="2354" />, whereas others might define extra keywords, related links etc for SEO.
It could probably all go into a db at some stage, but xhtml is pretty flexible while i have yet to discover the extent of the fields needed. Hoped i could make xml editor recognise some custom attributes/offer prompts/default values etc. When I use the second example my docs get lost by either html tidy or php dom. Thanks though, nice knowing its not the xml syntax